# Elasticsearch 2.x - new bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

After upgrading to Elasticsearch 2.x I got an issue with the following query:

```
{   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "_type": [
                        "xxx",
                        "yyy"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "aaa"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "bbb"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "ccc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "_type": "eee"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "f": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }   } }
```

Basically, I do not know how to replace the 'must' inside the 'should' filter with the new query DSL rules in Elasticsearch 2.x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Actually it is still working.                                                                  However, the use of "filtered" and "must" is deprecated with the new upgrade of ES. Therefore I am changing my code with the new rules.   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

Comment: You can simply remove `filtered/filter` and it will work.

Comment: Then I get this error :   "type": "query_parsing_exception",  "reason": "No query registered for [filter]"  The correct syntax now is the following    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the `filtered/filter` part and modify your query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_type": [
                    "xxx",
                    "yyy"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "aaa"
                }
              },
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "bbb"
                }
              },
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "ccc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": "eee"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "f": 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Also by changing "must" with "filter" I get the same previous search result (without score).

Comment: Yes that's correct about scoring. `must` should be used if you need socring, otherwise, you can use `filter` instead.